# Modifying a Excel sheet using PHP

Tags: php, excel

I want to modify a already existing excel sheet using PHP.

I tried to use pear class Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer.But this class is used to entirely create a new excel sheet and write in it.

Is there some way i can modify the already existing excel sheet using PHP?

Comment: thanks for the solution guys. As i already said in my post i know the there is a way to write into the excel sheet and what i am looking for is a way to modify it? :)

Comment: See, I don't think that that is possible in the conventional sense of "modify". Since the majority of these libraries do a complete read of the excel "object" and make it into an object that the library can manipulate. That would mean, that the data that is manipulated is not the excel file itself, but a copy of the data/formatting/sheets it contains. And it would therefore stand to reason, that modifying a document would require creation of a new document. BUT, there may be a library out there that does this, but for now, I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 2):

I do believe, that [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) class can help you out, but you may have to do a read and then a complete rewrite to another spreadsheet. I do not know, if the class allows for just modification.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for this is contained in [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)... but... one can not modify an existing file. You have to open it, read the data, and write the modified data while creating a new excel file.

Its very good documented, accessing the data is very easy. A whole separate documentation is made for reading spreadsheet files.